Does the website limit how many pages of results I can view?
Goal: I am trying to web scrape all the available NFTs from Foundation.app.
Setting: To do this, I went to this webpage: https://foundation.app/browse/nfts. In this webpage, you can see a few NFTs and apply any desired filtering actions. The webpage displays only part of the available NFTs, but if you scroll to the bottom of the webpage more NFTs will appear.
Solution: I figured that to pull these NFTs, I can do the following. First, go to the network tab on my browser and figure how the webpage is pulling new data, whenever one scrolls to the bottom of said webpage. Then, I can replicate this command and iterate over it to pull the new data myself, until I reach the end. Therefore, I had a look at how the webpage pulls new data and replicated it in R using the following code. In the working example code below, there is an argument called "page":1 which you can increase (from 1 to 2, 3, etc.) so that you get the next batch of NFTs.
    library(httr)
    library(jsonlite)
    
    headers = c(
      `Accept` = "*/*",
      `Accept-Language` = "en-US,en;q=0.9",
      `Connection` = "keep-alive",
      `Content-Type` = "application/json",
      `Origin` = "https://foundation.app",
      `Referer` = "https://foundation.app/",
      `Sec-Fetch-Dest` = "empty",
      `Sec-Fetch-Mode` = "cors",
      `Sec-Fetch-Site` = "same-site",
      `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
      `sec-ch-ua` = '"Chromium";v="124", "Google Chrome";v="124", "Not-A.Brand";v="99"',
      `sec-ch-ua-mobile` = "?0",
      `sec-ch-ua-platform` = '"Windows"'
    )
    
    data = '{"query":"\\n    query Nfts($accountAddress: ID, $collectionAddresses: [ID], $marketAvailability: NftMarketAvailability, $distinctAssetKey: String, $sort: NftSortOption, $page: Int, $perPage: Int, $distinct: Boolean) {\\n  nftsSearch(\\n    accountAddress: $accountAddress\\n    collectionAddresses: $collectionAddresses\\n    marketAvailability: $marketAvailability\\n    distinctAssetKey: $distinctAssetKey\\n    sort: $sort\\n    page: $page\\n    perPage: $perPage\\n    distinct: $distinct\\n  ) {\\n    items: nfts\\n    counts {\\n      collectionCounts\\n      marketAvailabilityCounts\\n      distinctCounts\\n    }\\n    page\\n    perPage\\n    totalPages\\n  }\\n}\\n    ","variables":{"marketAvailability":null,"sort":"DEFAULT","distinct":true,"page":1}}'
    
    res <- httr::POST(url = "https://api-v2.foundation.app/graphql", httr::add_headers(.headers=headers), body = data) 
    returned.results <- fromJSON(rawToChar(res$content)) 
    returned.results 
    returned.results$data$nftsSearch$items$collection$contractType

Problem: Although I've been able to replicate get the results for the first 20 pages, the website returns no results for the pages that follow. I know that there are more results available since the webpage shows there are about 90k NFTs available (and from the first 20 pages you get about 1k NFTs). I also know that the server has not banned or timed me out, because after going to page 21 and getting no results, I can once again get results for pages with a number less than or equal to 20. Therefore, my question is: Is there any way to get the remaining pages or is this limited by the website's backend?
